# How does Blazor Server route

Tags: c#, blazor

There isnt a ton of documentation on the Blazor server app, and I know it uses SignalR, but the project does not contain a HomeController. So I am wondering how is routing down in blazor without it? Is it just base on Role/Policy authorization for pages and components?

Comment: You have a `Router` component in `App.razor`. Please do some [research](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0) before asking or clarify your problem/question.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very specific, but the routing in a blazor app is done by `Router` component in the `App.razor`. The `Router` will scan the given Assembly for razor-components that have the `@page` directive. These razor-components are routable and will be able to get displayed by the `RouteView`-component.

App.razor:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

For authorization there is another `RouteView`-component called `AuthorizeRouteView`, but this requires that you wrap the whole `Route`-component with a `CascadingAuthenticationState`.

App.razor with auth:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" 
                DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Basic routing is pretty well described in this [Microsoft docu here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0).
For auth with routing there is also a docu article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks for explaining it.